# What's the difference between these property definitions in C#

Tags: c#

```
class myClass
{
 int age;

 public int Age
{
 get{return age;}
 set{age = value;}
}
```

Versus

```
class myClass
{
 public int Age{get; set;}
}
```

What's the difference between these two? Are they both the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They both compile to the same IL.

An automatic property is simply shorthand for the same thing with a private backing field (your first example).

From [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) on MSDN:

> When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

---

As @svick [commented](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204270/whats-the-difference-on-properties-c/204275?noredirect=1#comment399302_204275), the obvious difference is that you can access the backing field directly in your first example, whereas you can't in the second (as it is a generated, anonymous field).

Comment: There is one obvious difference: in the first case, you can access the field directly, in the second, you can't. This could matter if you want to use the field in a `ref` method, or something like that.